# Data conflict resolution in Silverlight with WCF Service

Tags: silverlight, wcf

When using Silverlight together with a WCF Services library how do you solve the age old possibility of two different users loading a record, making different changes to that record and then updating. In other words when updating how does the WCF service know that the data it retrieved is the same as the data it fetched before applying an update?

Do you need to check the original loaded values against the values in the database (i.e. recall the original query before updating)?

I was hoping that there would be a more out-of-the-box answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean using EntityFramework?  If so, here is the strategy I used :

When retrieving data on the client side you see that the "RowState" property of the entity is gone.  What I did is I added the property on the client side using the "partial class" feature.  And I manage locally the value of that RowState value.

When the data goes back to the server for update only send what has been modified filtering by the "RowState" property.

On your Update method, call the ApplyCurrentValues() method of the object.

Maybe there is a better solution for that, but that's what I am using on my project; and it works well on my case :)

Good luck

Comment: I'll give that a look - funnily enough I have another post on this site asking about Entity Framework and its use because I am not that sure about it.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure? I have a WCF Service library using a Data Access library to get the data. When I call the service the data is returned via the service to the client. Where would EF be?